# Django - Save in one model, access in another

Tags: django

I'm developing an app that lets users create Events and sign-up for a lottery to attend the event. As such, I need to create model methods that randomize those who have entered the lottery, and keep track of how many lotteries each user has won.

I'm trying to define a randomize model method in 1 model (Events), but the model method involves making changes to another model attribute (UserProfile). If I run the method randomize() on an event, the userprofile.events_attended attribute doesn't update.

I've searched, and unfortunately haven't been able to find any suitable answers on Stack Overflow. Any help on how to best accomplish this is much appreciated.

### models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    hosts = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    guests = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField()
    duration = models.DurationField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('event_detail', args=[self.id])

    def randomize(self):
        guests = self.guests
        random = self.attendees.order_by('?')[:guests]
        for i in random:
            i.events_attended = i.events_attended + 1
            i.save()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']


class UserProfile(models.Model):


    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    year = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=5, choices=YEAR_CHOICES)
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True, related_name="attendees")
    events_created = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    events_attended = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    lottery_points = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def net_lottery_points(self):
        events_attended = self.events_attended
        lottery_points = self.lottery_points
        events_created = Event.objects.filter(created_by=self.user).count()
        if events_created - events_attended <= 0:
           lottery_points = 0
        else:
            lottery_points = events_created - events_attended
        return lottery_points
```

Comment: And you say it's not working? It should! Side note: you can use this notation `i.events_attended += 1`

Comment: It's not working unfortunately. Any time I try to call the randomize method on another event, the events_attended attribute on UserProfile is overwritten.

Comment: Please show how you are verifying that the profiles do not change.

Comment: In the Python shell, I'm verifying by:

1) Adding an Event object;
2) Calling the randomize method on the Event object so that the user who created the event "wins" the lottery;
3) Calling net_lottery_points on the user that created the Event, which increments by 1 because an event has been created by the user, but in reality it should not change because I ran the randomize method (and thus the user who created the event also won lottery)
4) Calling user.events_attended and user.events_created results in 0 for both values.